# Is the root index.php file part of the Core?

Tags: updates, core

The contents of the `/index.php` is as follows:

```
/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

If I make any changes in this file, then do a Wordpress Update, will the contents of this file be replaced? I've not been able to find any references online for this file, only Wordpress' `/wp-includes` and `/wp-admin` folders.

I don't have access to the php.ini file and want to change the session cookie lifetime setting by adding the following code:

```
    $seconds = 31557600; //1 year
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $seconds);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $seconds);
```

but don't want to add it to a file that potentially could be overridden in a couple of months time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, index.php is part of core and is liable to be overwritten.

In fact, if you look at the [process to manually update WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update), step 7 is:

> Upload all new loose files from the root directory of the new version to your existing WordPress root directory

That may include index.php.

You can put custom PHP code in a custom plugin or theme. If using a pre-built theme, first [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and then put your code in that child theme's functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

If you run PHP as Apache module you can set `php.ini` values in `.htaccess`:

```
AllowOverride Options
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 31557600
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 31557600
```

Comment: I tried that but got a 500 internal server error.

Comment: You can create a `*.php` file with <?php phpinfo(); ?>  which will give you all the information about your PHP configuration. This way you' ll figure out is your PHP an Apache module or CGI module.

Comment: Also, may be you have to read about `AllowOverride`, but it's out of WordPress scope.